# How to optimize neural networks using meta-heuristic optimization algorithms? (PyTorch)

Tags: optimization, deep-learning, neural-network

I am currently studying the use of meta-heuristic optimization algorithms to optimize neural networks, but all I have found are optimizing neural networks such as BP and ANN.
I have a neural network built using PyTorch, the code is as follows. I would like to ask the following, how should I combine meta-inspired optimization algorithms (such as particle swarm optimization algorithm, genetic optimization algorithm, annealing optimization algorithm, etc.) to optimize?

```
from torch import nn
import torch
import torch.nn.functional as F


class Attention(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, hidden_size):
        super(Attention, self).__init__()
        self.hidden_size = hidden_size
        self.weight = nn.Parameter(torch.Tensor(hidden_size, 1))
        self.bias = nn.Parameter(torch.Tensor(1))
        self.softmax = nn.Softmax(dim=1)

        nn.init.xavier_uniform_(self.weight)
        nn.init.zeros_(self.bias)

    def forward(self, inputs):
        scores = torch.matmul(inputs, self.weight).squeeze(2) + self.bias
        attn_weights = self.softmax(scores).unsqueeze(2)

        attn_output = torch.sum(attn_weights * inputs, dim=1)

        return attn_output


class Net(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Net, self).__init__()
        self.noise_model = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Conv1d(in_channels=3, out_channels=64, kernel_size=1),
            nn.BatchNorm1d(64),
            nn.ReLU(inplace=True),
            nn.Conv1d(in_channels=64, out_channels=128, kernel_size=1),
            nn.BatchNorm1d(128),
            nn.ReLU(inplace=True),
            nn.Conv1d(in_channels=128, out_channels=256, kernel_size=1),
            nn.BatchNorm1d(256),
            nn.ReLU(inplace=True)
        )

        self.point_model = nn.Sequential( 
            nn.Conv1d(in_channels=3, out_channels=64, kernel_size=1),
            nn.BatchNorm1d(64),
            nn.ReLU(inplace=True),
            nn.Conv1d(in_channels=64, out_channels=128, kernel_size=1),
            nn.BatchNorm1d(128),
            nn.ReLU(inplace=True),
            nn.Conv1d(in_channels=128, out_channels=256, kernel_size=1),
            nn.BatchNorm1d(256),
            nn.ReLU(inplace=True)
        )

        self.color_model = nn.Sequential( 
            nn.Conv2d(3, 16, kernel_size=3, stride=1, padding=1), 
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=2, stride=2), 
            nn.Conv2d(16, 32, kernel_size=3, stride=1, padding=1), 
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=2, stride=2),
            nn.Conv2d(32, 64, kernel_size=3, stride=1, padding=1),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=2, stride=2), 
            nn.Flatten(), 
            nn.Linear(64 * 28 * 28, 256), 
        )

        self.depth_model = nn.Sequential( 
            nn.Conv2d(1, 16, kernel_size=3, stride=1, padding=1), 
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=2, stride=2), 
            nn.Conv2d(16, 32, kernel_size=3, stride=1, padding=1), 
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=2, stride=2), 
            nn.Conv2d(32, 64, kernel_size=3, stride=1, padding=1), 
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=2, stride=2),
            nn.Flatten(),
            nn.Linear(64 * 28 * 28, 256), 
        )

        self.attention = Attention(256)  
        self.layer1 = nn.Linear(1058, 1036) 

        self.output = nn.Sequential( 
            nn.Conv1d(in_channels=256, out_channels=128, kernel_size=1),
            nn.BatchNorm1d(128),
            nn.ReLU(inplace=True),
            nn.Conv1d(in_channels=128, out_channels=64, kernel_size=1),
            nn.BatchNorm1d(64),
            nn.ReLU(inplace=True),
            nn.Conv1d(in_channels=64, out_channels=3, kernel_size=1),
        )

    def forward(self, noise_data, point_data, color_data, depth_data):
        noise_feature = self.noise_model(noise_data.permute(0, 2, 1)) 
        point_feature = self.point_model(point_data.permute(0, 2, 1)) 
        color_feature = self.color_model(color_data) 
        depth_feature = self.depth_model(depth_data) 

        concat_feature = torch.cat(
            [noise_feature, point_feature, color_feature.unsqueeze(2), depth_feature.unsqueeze(2)], dim=2)

        concat_att = self.attention(concat_feature.permute(0, 2, 1))

        concat_feature = concat_feature + concat_att.unsqueeze(2)

        concat_feature = self.layer1(concat_feature)
        output = self.output(concat_feature).permute(0, 2, 1)
        return output
```

I checked a lot of information, but none of them taught me how to combine optimization. Most of them optimize the initial weights and biases of BP and ANN neural networks, etc. There are no tutorials for using PyTorch. So go out of your way to ask for help.